# Configuring web.xml for jsp/servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

This is my structure of my Web application

```
Webcontent
-Admin
--1.jsp
--2.jsp
-User
--1.jsp
--2.jsp
-login.jsp
```

This is my web.xml file

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resolve_subject</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>teacher_select.resolve_subject</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resolve_subject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resolve_subject</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And this is how I call my servlet from 1.jsp

```
function showCity(str){
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
    xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  if (xmlHttp==null){
  alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request");
  return;
  } 
  var url="resolve_subject";
  url +="?count=" +str;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange1;
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  }
```

But I get the following error
[image]

Comment: why dont you try this `var url="./resolve_subject?count="+str;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite expected. Your servlet is mapped to `/resolve_subject`. That means that it's at the root of your webapp. Its absolute URL is thus `/qmsnew/resolve_subject`. But you're trying to access it with a relative path, from a JSP under `/admin`, leading to an absolute path of `/qmsnew/admin/resolve_subject`.

Your URL should thus be

```
var url = "../resolve_subject";
```

or,

```
var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resolve_subject";
```

or, using the JSTL:

```
var url = "<c:url value='/resolve_subject' />";
```

Side note: pleasue respect the Java naming conventions. Classes are CamelCased. Your servlet should thus be named `ResolveSubject`.